# Convert UIImage from 32bitRGB or PNG to 1 bit Indexed color in Swift

Tags: swift, png, rgb

How do I convert a 32bit RBG or PNG into a 1 bit INDEXED color format in Swift? All I have about the color format is that it uses a palette with 2 colors and stores each pixel in 1 bit.

I've see converting from 32bit to 16bit:

```
    guard let imagePixels32Bit = image.pixelData32bitRGB() else {
        return
    }
    
    let imagePixels: [UInt8]
    

    // Convert 32bit color data to 16bit
    var r: UInt8 = 0, g: UInt8 = 0
    var pixels = [UInt8]()
        
    for (i, value) in imagePixels32Bit.enumerated() {
        let j = i % 4
        if j == 0 {
            r = value
        }
        else if j == 1 {
            g = value
        }
        else if j == 2 {
            let b = value
                
            let rgb16 = (UInt16(r & 0xF8) << 8) | (UInt16(g & 0xFC) << 3) | UInt16(b >> 3)
            pixels.append(contentsOf: rgb16.toBytes)
        }
    }
    
    
    imagePixels = pixels
```

Can anybody help with the conversion? I'm not sure of the file format for a 1 bit indexed color.